# D3.js : How to calculate accurately the Mercator transformation ratio `r`?

Tags: d3.js, gis, projection, topojson, mercator

Given a square ABCD on Earth's surface (Equirectangular), with A & B on the Greenwitch meridian, B & C on meridian longitude = 10⁰ :

```
A( 0.0; 50.0)          C(10.0; 50.0)

B( 0.0; 40.0)          B(10.0; 40.0)
```

Given my D3js dataviz works in `d3.geo.mercator()` projection, my square is vertically transformed by a ratio `r= mercator_height in px/width in px` about 1.5.

**How to calculate accurately this Mercator transformation ratio `r` ?**

Note: this is non-linear since it imply some `1/cos()` [2].

---

**Edit:** I'am tempted to think we should first reproject each point using `d3.geo.mercator()` on the screen (**HOW? Which syntax ?**), so `D3` do all the hard maths. We could then GET the point's pixels coordinates, so we can calculate the length AB and the length AC in pixels, and finally `r=AC/AB`. Also, it's a bit **how to convert decimal degrees coordinates into projected pixels coordinates function of the chosen `d3.geo.<PROJECTIONNAME>()` ?**

[2]: [Mercator: scale factor is changed along the meridians as a function of latitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110730/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the points are A: (0, 50), B: (0, 40), C: (10, 50) and D: (10, 40). The feature enclosed by the points (A, C, D, B) will look as a square using the equirectangular projection. Now, the points are longitude, latitude pairs, you can compute the great-arc distance between the points using [`d3.geo.distance`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-distance). This will give you the angular distance between the points. For instance:

```
// Points (lon, lat)
var A = [ 0, 50],
    B = [ 0, 40],
    C = [10, 50],
    D = [10, 40];

// Geographic distance between AB and AC
var distAB = d3.geo.distance(A, B),  // 0.17453292519943306 radians
    distAC = d3.geo.distance(A, C);  // 0.11210395570214343 radians
```

Now, these distances are the angles between the points, as you can see, the feature wasn't a square. If we project the points using the [D3 Mercator projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-mercator):

```
// The map will fit in 800 px horizontally
var width = 800;
var mercator = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(width / (2 * Math.PI));

// Project (lon, lat) points using the projection, to get pixel coordinates.
var pA = mercator(A),  // [480, 121] (rounded)
    pB = mercator(B),  // [480, 152] (rounded)
    pC = mercator(C);  // [502, 121] (rounded)
```

And now use the euclidean distance to compute the distance between the projected points `pA`, `pB` and `pC`.

```
function dist(p, q) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p[0] - q[0], 2) + Math.pow(p[1] - q[1], 2));
}

var pDistAB = dist(pA, pB),  // 31.54750649588999 pixels
    pDistAC = dist(pA, pC);  // 22.22222222222223 pixels
```

If you use angular distances as reference, you will get two ratios, one for AB and other for AC:

```
var ratioAB = distAB / pDistAB, // 0.005532384159178197 radians/pixels
    ratioAC = distAC / pDistAC; // 0.005044678006596453 radians/pixels
```

If you use the equirectangular projection as reference, you can use the euclidean distance between the points (as if they were in a plane surface):

```
var ratioAB = dist(A, B) / pDistAB, // 0.3169822629659431  degrees/pixels
    ratioAC = dist(A, C) / pDistAC; // 0.44999999999999984 degrees/pixels
```

Comment: I think you want `r = ratioAC / ratioAB = 1.41` (the second version).